# Inject service without using constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to create a generic http service that would do all basic http requests. So, the service might look like this:

```
export class GenericService {
constructor(
private http: HttpClient
) {
  this.data();
}
data() {
  return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/..../`)
    .pipe(map(data => {
    return  data;
  }));
 }
```

}
I then want to create a data pipe that I will extend every component with. That class might look like this:

```
  export class DataPipe implements OnDestroy {
  subscription;
  constructor(private dataSvc: GenericService) {
  }
  getData(source: any) {
  this.subscription = this.dataSvc.data()
    .subscribe(data => {
    source = data;
  });
  } 
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
 }
```

Finally, a component:

```
    export class Component extends DataPipe {
    source: any;
    constructor() {
     super(GenericService);
   }

   getData(source);
 }
```

I am assuming that the "source" that is passed to getData() will get actual value. Even if it worked, I am getting an error at super(GenericService); since GenericService's constructor expects a parameter. Ideally, I wouldn't even want to deal with GenericService in a component. All a developer needs to know is to extend his component with DataPipe class and call getData(). Am I even going to the right direction with such architecture?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want to inform you.

1. `HttpClient` is a `singleton` service in the whole project, if you imported `HttpClientModule` in the `app.module.ts`,
2. requests made by `HttpClient`, they will be closed automatically after receiving a result from the server.

I recommend you simply import the service and call the function (which will send request to the server) from component where you need to get the necessary data from server

Here is the simple example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-cwrdrr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Why would 2. be of any problem? Yes, I agree it's very simple to have each and component doing the same subscription for getting data. I am trying to avoid that by designing a data payer that would hide all subscription complicity. It also will allow future modifications when Angular/Rxjs change their specifications.

Comment: @Mark Sorry I wrote wrong the 2 point. I have updated the answer, it should be: **requests made by HttpClient, they will be closed automatically after receiving a result from the server.**

Comment: Ok, but why is it bad?

Comment: @Mark it is not bad you have unsubscribed from request on `ngOnDestroy`, it is already closed. you have not any memory like issues.

Comment: @Mark Are you checked the example? are you seen console logs?